# How to use the filter flag in drush config:status

Tags: drush

I am using Drush 10.3.6.

Drush config:status gives me:

```
# drush config:status
 --------------------------------- ------------ 
  Name                              State       
 --------------------------------- ------------ 
  webform.settings                  Different   
  webform.webform.contact           Only in DB  
  webform.webform.example_webform   Only in DB  
 --------------------------------- ------------
```

I am interested in filtering this to display only certain items, however the filter parameter does not work as expected:

```
# drush help config:status|grep Filter
  --filter[=FILTER] Filter output based on provided expression    

# drush --filter='^webform\.webform\..*$' config:status
In OperatorFactory.php line 50:
  Could not parse expression ^webform\.webform\..*$  

# drush --filter='webform.webform.*' config:status
In OperatorFactory.php line 50:
  Could not parse expression webform.webform.*
```

What is format of the expression that needs to be passed to the filter parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the *Consolidation\Filter\OperatorFactory* class mentioned with the error, you'll see documentation at the top of the Class that outlines the acceptable syntax.

```
**
 * Convert a simple operator expression into an Operator.
 *
 * The supported operators include:
 *
 *      key=value           Equals
 *      key*=value          Contains value
 *      key~=#regex#        Regular expression match
 *
 * It is also possible to negate the result of an operator by
 * adding a logical-not operator either before the entire expression,
 * e.g. !key=value, or before the operator, e.g. key!=value.
 *
 */
```

Using the above documentation as a guide, the following all work for me - examples two and three should work for your example case.

```
// 1. Use the *Equals* option to show only the config entity with name "webform.webform.contact"
drush --filter="name=webform.webform.contact" config:status

// 2. Use the *Contains value* option to show any config entity with name containing "webform.webform"
drush --filter="name*=webform.webform" config:status

// 3. Use the *Regular expression match* option to show any config entity with name starting with "webform.webform."
drush --filter="name~=#^webform\.webform\.*#" config:status
```